# Failed on get row: java.sql.SQLException: getByte Failed on value ( )

Tags: java

The exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: getByte Failed on value (  ) in column 49
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.getByte(CachedRowSetImpl.java:1794)
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.getByte(CachedRowSetImpl.java:2512)
```

The code is this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    byte synchronisationStatus = rs.getByte(validColumnName);
}
```

The ResultSet is also valid and has default value in this(validColumnName) set to 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: provide more information regarding data which you want to fetch ..

Comment: What datatype does `validColumnName` have?

Comment: To clarify: I mean the respective column in the database

Comment: Hi! That was a problem, as I didn't have access to database, could not determine that was the case. Therefore data type was varchar and I was trying to fetch byte.

Comment: So it works now? getByte() should actually be able to query a varchar field, but instead of the varchar it will retrieve the byte value of the string stored in there (same for numeric datatypes). It just doesn't work on the more "fancy" types like date, timestamp etc.

Comment: Yes, it does, I got an access to change the datatype. Thanks for your comment. Put it in the answer please, so I can choose the best one, and close the question. Others might benefit from your answer also.